# Create a stored procedure in mysql which deletes the row if exists, if not insert an value

Tags: mysql

I have written the below procedure but when it executes the table always keep only one data in it and rest is deleted whenever  a call made to the Stored Procedure.

So finally only the  latest value is stored and the rest all gets deleted, so i end up in getting only one result data from my table .

Is there any thing wrong i am doing in the below procedure?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `PersonVisitInfo`(personid varchar(254),visits int )
BEGIN
declare _personid varchar(254);
declare _visit_count int;
declare oldest_item varchar(254);

set _personid   = personid;
set _visit_count = visits;

delete from personData where personid = _personid ;

if (select count(*) from personData where personid = _personid) >= _visit_count then
    SELECT id into oldest_item FROM personData  WHERE personid = _personid ORDER BY lastvisitdate LIMIT 1;
    DELETE FROM personData WHERE id = oldest_item; 
end if;

insert into personData(id, personid, lastvisitdate) values(UUID(), _personid, now());

END$$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove this line:

```
delete from personData where personid = _personid ;
```

This removes all the person's records from the table, meaning that the following if statement will always be false, and the last line will insert the new record - which will be the only record for that person.

Comment: why the where condition doesn't get checked?

Comment: @PishangUjeniya my condition gets  checked with where condition . The mistake here was personid  was not primary key . so i had all records with same personid.

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from personData where personid = _personid ;

if (select count(*) from personData where personid = _personid) >= _visit_count
```

But you've just deleted all the rows - so the 'if' statement will never be true.

Leaving that aside, why not just have a unique key on personid and use 'REPLACE' or 'INSERT....ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE' instead:

Comment: i assumed that delete from personData where personid=_personid will just delete if the person id are same .

Comment: @Malcolm I also assumed the same, and have been struggling with this since last an hour.

My Procedure doesn't even check for the where condition for `user_uuid` .